# spamassasin config to score empty subject

Tags: regex, email, spam, spamassassin

I am aware of how to set spamassasin to penalize (score) a mail containing a .ZIP file, which goes like this:

```
mimeheader MY_CNF_ZIP   Content-Type =~ /^application\/zip/
score      MY_CNF_ZIP   1.5
```

But I am not sure how to **write a rule for empty subject** (recently more and more spams with empty subject are received...)

Shall this be correct?:

```
header MY_CNF_EMPTYSUB    Subject =~ /^$/
score  MY_CNF_EMPTYSUB    1.5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes this should work like a charm :)

For information, there is a MISSING_SUBJECT rule on SA which check if Subject header field is present are not. But not if present and empty ...

Comment: The distinction is not very meaningful anyway.  Also, I don't actually see a lot of spam with empty subject lines.  Perhaps you are using a client which displays *invalid* subjects as empty?  There's plenty of that in my inbox (mainly Cyrillic subjects without any encoding specified, so just a bunch of non-ASCII bytes.)

Comment: @tripleee: Might be. In any event, I can see it working now examining some spam e-mail headers and they, indeed have got MY_CNF_EMPTYSUB score. Thank you, folks